# How to get a Python package depending on a package with extra dependency to install that extra dependency?

Tags: python, package

I have made a Python package. In it I have the following dependency in `setup.py`:

```
install_requires=[
    'scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.19.1',
]
```

But when I install my package, `scipy`, which is installed as an extra dependency of `scikit-learn` is not installed. Why I do:

```
pip install my_package
```

If I do:

```
pip install scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.19.1
```

An extra dependency `scipy` is installed.

How can I make my package depend on extra dependencies? I do not want my package to have any optional dependencies. I need all dependencies of `scikit-learn`, core and extra.

Comment: It should do.  Make sure you're using the most recent version of `setuptools` and `pip`.

Comment: It seems it is a bug: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4957#issuecomment-356186676